# Is this a normal format/size for a Symmetric Key?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, aes

**This function creates a symmetric and asymmetric keys and then generates a QR Code with both public and symmetric key and some other data:**

```
      private void initQRCode() {
            String qrString = "";
                try {
                    Random r = new Random();
                    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
                    keyPairGenerator.initialize(256, new SecureRandom());
                    KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

                    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
                    keyGenerator.init(256); // for example
                    SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();


                    byte [] pubBytes = keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded();
                    byte [] symBytes = secretKey.getEncoded();
                    String publicKey = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(pubBytes,0);
                    String symKey = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(symBytes,0);

                    long groupID =  r.nextLong();
                    int tutorID = r. nextInt();

                    System.out.println(publicKey);
                    System.out.println(symKey);
                    System.out.println(groupID);
                    System.out.println(tutorID);

                    qrString = publicKey + ":::" + symKey  + ":::" + groupID + ":::" + tutorID;

                }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
               if(qrString != "") {
                   StringBuilder textToSend = new StringBuilder();
                   textToSend.append(qrString);
                   MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
                   try {
                       BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(textToSend.toString(), BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 600, 600);
                       BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
                       Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
                       imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                       imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                   } catch (WriterException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
        }
```

**Final QR CODE Result:**
MDwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADKwAwKAIhAK6saelQTFFeGgAcuxH9GKmMqFXlVSck1S4aEYMh9ASt
AgMBAAE=
:::/3aktO5322KlHLTwVY490S6/rpXW1z0Ga30+HKNI64E=
:::2629194659936505759:::1529276565

Comment: Your AES-key has a length of 256 bit or 32 byte and that is the maximum key length for AES symmetric encryption. 
The generation of the RSA-keypair with 256 bit key length is definitely too short - today's minimum should be 2048 bit. 
As there is a "normal" encoding of a key I cannot answer your question. Base64 is mostly used when the key needs to get printed out or transfered e.g. by mail. Using a QR-code needs a reader o the other side that knows what data is "inside" the QR-code so Base64 encoding is not necessary.